# How to get the high frequency portions of an audio using DWT?

Tags: audio, frequency, dwt

I basically want to use a digital wavelet transform to get the high frequencies of an audio signal and get the time information or really anything that can make me understand where they happen so I can compare with the data I get by reading the audio so I can perform some operations on the samples that have a high frequency.

I'm new to signal processing but I have studied a scientific paper that used DWT for that and I want to try to replicate that idea.

Yes I have studied DWT and what got me into it was the fact that you can get time information from it, as far as I understand. And I know about the coefficients but I don't know what to do with them exactly.

For all that, I'm using **scipy** to read a ***wav*** file and getting "data" that I suppose is the amplitude of every sample, the [*scipy.io.wavfile.read* documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.read.html) doesn't make that clear). For the DWT itself, I'm using [PyWavelets](https://pywavelets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/dwt-discrete-wavelet-transform.html).

This is what I have right now (adapted):

```
from scipy.io import wavfile
import numpy as np
import pywt

sample_rate, data = wavfile.read('test.wav')

coefficientsApproximation, coefficientsDetail = pywt.dwt(data, 'db1')

coefficientsApproximation = np.array(coefficientsApproximation)
coefficientsDetail = np.array(coefficientsDetail)
```

The length of *data* is the **number of samples**. If I divide it by the sample rate I get the length of the audio in seconds, as expected.

The *data* itself is presented like this:

```
array([[ 19,  20],
       [ 19,  19],
       [ 20,  19],
       ...,
       [-84, -84],
       [-75, -75],
       [-74, -74]], dtype=int16)
```

Which is a 2D numpy array (2D because the audio is stereo, but don't focus on that cause I'm also working with mono).

*coefficientsDetail* is presented like this:

```
array([[-0.70710678],
       [ 0.        ],
       [ 0.70710678],
       ...,
       [ 0.        ],
       [ 0.        ],
       [ 0.        ]])
```

Which is again a 2D numpy array.

*coefficientsApproximation* is presented similarly:

```
array([[  27.57716447],
       [  26.87005769],
       [  27.57716447],
       ...,
       [-118.79393924],
       [-106.06601718],
       [-104.65180362]])
```

I want to use the information of WHERE are the high frequencies happening so that I can actually change the *data* variable based on that (e.g. change all the values related to a high frequency to 20). I tried to find a way to use the values of *coefficientsDetail* in order to do that but I wasn't able to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any highpass filter will give you high frequency time information.

A standard method for analysing and processing audio is a windowed/overlapped fft filterbank. I would suggest using that as a starting point as you will find more references and code snippets and litterature. Then, if you want to achieve something more specific, wavelets may well be the choice.